# get Generated key for jdbc execute batch

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to fetch all generated keys for storing arraylist values in database in jdbc batch updation
and I would like to set generated value in `pmu.setId();`

I am using Mysql Database and driver `mysql-connector-java 5.1.14`

My code is :

```
ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
for (PostMessageUsers pmu : pmuList) {
                    ps1.setLong(1, pm.getMessageid());
                    ps1.setLong(2, pmu.getAtomByReceivedBy().getId());
                    ps1.setLong(3, pmu.getAtomBySentBy().getId());
                    ps1.setLong(4, pmu.getAtomByAuthor().getId());
                    ps1.addBatch();
                    if (++batchCount % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                        ps1.executeBatch();
                        res = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
                        if (res.next()) {
                            pmu.setId((long) res.getInt(1));
                        }
                    }
                }
                int postMessageUsers[] = ps1.executeBatch();
            }
```

I am able to get gererated id  inside `if (++batchCount % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {`

But I would like to know how to get gererated id for last `int postMessageUsers[] = ps1.executeBatch();`
If above statement executes how can i get generated id for this.

Comment: after `int postMessageUsers[] = ps1.executeBatch();` shoul i also include `res = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
                        if (res.next()) {
                            pmu.setId((long) res.getInt(1));`
                        }`

Comment: What is your question? Note that whether `getGeneratedKeys` is supported on a batch execute is JDBC driver implementation specific, as it is not required by JDBC IIRC.

Comment: I have included executeBatch in two places I would like to know to get all generated key. I have to include getGeneratedKeys after 2nd executeBatch also or not.

Comment: Please describe clearly **in your question** what you are trying to achieve, also describe what problems you are having with your current solution (I can see a few, but still). Also mention which JDBC driver and database you are using as it has a significant impact on it even being possible or not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Updated question. Please tell me if any other detail required